# How do i use the sysrq key on chromebook running ubuntu mate?

Tags: keyboard, reboot, mate, chromebook, sysrq

Running ubuntu mate 22.04 on samsung chromebook 4 with mrchromebox's rwlegacy firmware.

I heard that the sysrq key for chromebook is alt+f10 (volume up) but when i try to do a reisub, the r makes the chromebook force restart without the eisub parts thus causing hard drive unproper umounts. Is there a way to do the real sysrq on chromebook keyboards? If i use a external usb keyboard that has the key, it will work but i want to use the builtin keyboard.